# Delay before javascript executes

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following javascipt to centre text dynamically.

```
$(function() {
    $('.centre-dyn').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left' : '50%',
        'top' : '50%',
        'margin-left' : function() {return -$(this).outerWidth()/2},
        'margin-top' : function() {return -$(this).outerHeight()/2}
    });
});
```

However, when I load the page, the text appears in its uncentered position before quickly centring. How can I make the text immediately centre?

Comment: Use flex with pure CSS instead of JS code.

Comment: Why not just set CSS rules for this instead of using JavaScript?

Comment: Why are you not styling using css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop flash of unstyled content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640238/how-to-stop-flash-of-unstyled-content)

Answer (score 1):

One option is as Aurora0001 linked, to hide the content then show it once the JS runs. The other is to have the script tag right after the html element. So you don't need the document ready, and it will run immediately:

```
<div class="centre-dyn"></div>
<script>
    $('.centre-dyn').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left' : '50%',
        'top' : '50%',
        'margin-left' : function() {return -$(this).outerWidth()/2},
        'margin-top' : function() {return -$(this).outerHeight()/2}
    });
</script>
```

Provided jQuery is loaded in head tag or somewhere before this point in the document, that should work fine. But really i would suggest doing this in CSS instead, as per the comments.

Answer (score 1):

`$(function(){})` is a shorthand or `$(document).ready();` Your code is executing once the document is ready, not immediately. As others have mentioned: using css would make more sense, as well as have it be centered immediately.

For example:

```
.centre-dyn {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```